# All other CMS pages redirecting to home page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cms, cms-pages

I am creating a marketplace using Magento 1.9 and I have discovered that all my CMS pages like "about us", "contact", "terms and conditions" etc are not opening but are automatically redirecting to the home page. Even when I click on preview from the admin backend side they still redirect to homepage.  However product, category pages, login page and checkout pages are working. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. This is hard to tell without any further details. What changes did you make before that happened? Do the URLs look different? By default, Magento redirects to the home page if the base URL does not match, maybe that's related.

Comment: Yep, please share some code - likely you've cocked up the routing somehow .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's not a default Magento behavior so to me it sounds like it's caused by a module.

First try to reindex and flush your cache to see if it fixes the issue but I doubt it.

If the problem is still here you will have to find the module causing the problem and debug it.

To find the faulty module:

1. Create `app/etc/modules/deleted` folder
2. Move the first non core module file (not starting with `Mage_` ) under `app/etc/modules` to this`deleted`  folder
3. Flush the cache
4. See if the issue is still happening. If it is, repeat step 2; if not, you found the faulty module and you ll have to debug it to find what is the problem exactly.

Don't forget to move back all the files under `app/etc/modules/deleted` back to `app/etc/modules` once you're done and delete the ‘deleted` folder

Comment: I have found the module with the bug thanks. Its a third party marketplace extension i installed. However, i dont know hot to fix the bug issue with the module. Please assist. This is the only code in the module in app/etc/modules      <config>
    <modules>
        <Manthan_Marketplace>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Manthan_Marketplace>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: @Henry unfortunately I won't be able to help with that few information. Please contact the author of the module so he can assist

Comment: Problem solved by Opening app/code/Manthan/Marketplace/Controller/Router.php and then removing this first argument 'count($path >2)' from if condition .thats it.

Comment: @Henry glad you figured it out. Feel free to upvote my answer if it helped you